# CSS Grid not respecting row and column span rules and placing items in random order

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to develop a photo gallery using `CSS Grid`. I have `landscape` photos which end with `-l.jpeg` and `portrait` photos which end with `-p.jpeg`.

**Phtot Gallery `HTML`:**

```html
<article id="photos">
    <img src="./images/1-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/2-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/3-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/4-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/5-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/6-p.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/7-p.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/8-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/9-p.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/10-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/11-p.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/12-l.jpeg">
    <img src="./images/13-p.jpeg">
</article>
```

**Photo Gallery `CSS`**:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
} 

#photos {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 0.5em;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
```

This makes the photo gallery look like:

[image: Uneven Photo Gallery]

The photo gallery now has even spaces. To fix that I added the below css,

```css
#photos img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

[image: Zoomed landscape images]

But now landscape images are zoomed and not able to view the full wide image. So to fix that, I decided to `span` `portrait` images `vertically` by `2 rows` and `landscape` images `horizontally` by `2 columns` using the below css.

```css
#photos img[src$="-p.jpeg"] {
    grid-row-end: span-2;
}
```

Now grid looks like,

[image: Portrait Fixed]

Now when I add css for `landscape` images to span 2 `columns`,

```css
#photos img[src$="-l.jpeg"] {
    grid-column-end: span-2;
}
```

The grid makes a big uneven space as shown below,

[image: Grid collapsed]

Another thing I have noticed is that images are not placed in the expected order as per `HTML`. Here is the repo link - [CssGridPhotoGallery](https://github.com/fingers10/CSSGridPhotoGallery).

Please assist on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think the syntax for grid-row-end and grid-column-end should be "span 2" (no dash).
On my machine (Windows 11, Chrome), deleting the dash makes the layout better

Comment: oops that was the mistake. I'm sorry it's a very silly mistake. You can post this correct as answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for grid-row-end and grid-column-end should be as follows:

```
#photos img[src$="-p.jpeg"] {
    grid-row-end: span 2;
}
#photos img[src$="-l.jpeg"] {
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

Note the removed hyphens in the span values.

On my machine (Windows 11, Chrome), this corrected syntax gives a nicer looking layout, as below:

[image: Afer correcting span syntax]